# Brick pavers with 25 - 35mm gaps - Any Issue?

Tags: landscaping, pavers

Our landscaper has just finished laying about 35sqm of brick pavers. On inspection I noticed the majority are spaced with about a 20mm gap with some gaps as high as 35mm. Our driveway (which the current work is supposed to match) has spacing of 10mm +/- 5mm. Landscaper says the grout will be 1 part cement / 2 parts sand so the final surface will be very strong.

The grout is intended to be flush with bricks and high strength. But I'm a little concerned because I've never seen bricks laid so far apart before and everywhere I look the recommendation is for much smaller gaps.

Should I make them pull up the pavers and relay them. They've glued them to a sand cement bedding, so it will be a lot of work.

Current paving to be matched:
[image: Existing Pavers]

Pavers recently laid yet to be grouted.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Those seem huge gaps.  I would be upset with a gap of more than 1 or 2mm, let alone 10.

Comment: Imagine with those gaps, walking on it would not comfortable(even dangerous), unless the grout will be level with the top of the bricks.

Comment: If the work didn't match, then they haven't done the job properly, whatever the gap.  Do not pay till it all matches.

Comment: Even ten mm gap is unusually large.

Answer (score 2):

> Our driveway (which the current work is supposed to match) has spacing of 10mm +/- 5mm.

The current work does not match the work requested.

It doesn't matter that they said "the grout will be 1 part cement / 2 parts sand so the final surface will be very strong" because you're the one that has to live with this f*ck up after they go home.